# Get and Set not being called

Tags: c#

So I have a couple fields in a program that set the email subject and email body for an automated message.

My Email Settings class is this:

```
public static class Email
{
    public static string Body
    {
        get { return (string) SettingsStore.RetrieveSettingValue("emailBody"); }
        set { SettingsStore.StoreSetting(new Setting {SettingKey = "emailBody", 
                SettingValue = value}); }
    }

    public static string Subject
    {
        get { return (string) SettingsStore.RetrieveSettingValue("emailSubject"); }
        set { SettingsStore.StoreSetting(new Setting {SettingKey = "emailSubject",
                SettingValue = value}); }
    }
}
```

And my UI code that gets and sets the values is here:

```
private void ApplicationSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    subjectTextEdit.Text = Settings.Email.Subject;
    bodyTextEdit.Text = Settings.Email.Body;
}

private void ApplicationSettings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Email.Subject = subjectTextEdit.Text;
    Settings.Email.Body = bodyTextEdit.Text;
}
```

Oddly, my get and set methods in the Email Settings class are not being called- when I access this form for the first time after application start the fields are blank even when the values are in the database. After I edit the fields once and close that form then open the form again (without closing the entire application) the fields have the text I put into them.

I have set a breakpoint on the _Load and _FormClosing events and these are getting hit.
When I set a breakpoint on the get/set methods inside the settings class, the breakpoints are not getting hit.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint at `ApplicationSettings_Load` and step into the code (with `F11`)?

Comment: It just goes straight over the calls to Settings.Email.Subject/.Body, it doesn't go into them even when pressing Step Into.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `Email.Subject`? You are using `Settings.Email` which to me infers an INSTANCE reference which completely voids the use of `static`.

Comment: Do you have ["Skip over Properties" unchecked in your debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Lloyd - "Settings" is a public static class as well, which is a container for several settings subclasses (email, employee, etc).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I did have that checked, but oddly after unchecking it, the same behavior is still happening. The debugger highlights the "subjectTextEdit.Text = Settings.Email.Subject;" line and I press Step Into and it moves down to the next line and doesn't step in.

Comment: @koresho That doesn't matter because it would still be a reference of the `Settings` class in that case. Static classes are referred to by type name and not reference.

Comment: If you disassemble the assembly containing this code using ILSpy, does it contain the get/set property calls?

Comment: @Lloyd Interesting... I didn't know that. I moved the Email class out of Settings, so the call is just "subjectTextEdit.Text = Email.Subject;" and it didn't make a difference- exact same result.

Comment: Can you have the debugger stop in the `ApplicationSettings_Load` and then step into (F11) the call to Email.Subject and actually see where it's going?

Comment: @Amy - ILSpy shows what appears to be the auto-generated properties: // ScheduleSettings.Settings.Email
public static string Subject
{
 get;
 set;
}

Comment: @NickGotch - It doesn't go anywhere; I have unselected the "Skip over properties" option but even when using Step Into it just goes right over the property call instead of into it.

Comment: Strange. If you right-click on the Email.Subject in the `ApplicationSettings_Load` call and choose "Go to Definition" does that take you to the right place?

Comment: @NickGotch - It does. To everyone: Thanks for your help, I found the issue- the issue was Visual Studio, not the code. I closed VS, restarted the PC, opened VS, cleaned the solution, closed, reopened, built. There was an error in one of my referenced assemblies that was not appearing all the other times I built the project that appeared this time, and fixing that error caused all of this to work properly. I'd have never found this without your help (I'd still be scratching my head wondering how my code was wrong) so thank you all so much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To everyone: Thanks for your help, I found the issue- the issue was Visual Studio, not the code.

I closed VS, restarted the PC, opened VS, cleaned the solution, closed, reopened, built. There was an error in one of my referenced assemblies that was not appearing all the other times I built the project that appeared this time, and fixing that error caused all of this to work properly.

I'd have never found this without your help (I'd still be scratching my head wondering how my code was wrong) so thank you all so much! :)